# How to detect user inactivity from a apps running in the background?

Tags: android, service, background, user-inactivity

I'm trying to make an app that warns you when you stop using your phone for a while (so I dont stop doing my work). The functionality would be similar as a screensaver, after some minutes of inactivity would pop a annoying message. So, I made a service and I try to detect a onUserInteraction() to restart a timer that pops the massage, but that doesn't seem to work like would in a activity. Are there other ways of detecting inactivity or a more intelligent way to do this thing? thank you very much.

Comment: you really ought to post some code from your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You could register for the " android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" intent in your manifest, and set a timer with `AlarmManager`.